# i try to make a form in NodeJs for searching a user in mongodb by telephone number using query routing, i don't know why this not working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

What is the wrong with this code? I got the exactly mobile number on the console but not on query routing on /search_user?mob ?

```
<input type="tel" name="message" id="mobile_input" value="">
                  <!--getting mobile no. from the input tag -->
                  <script type="text/javascript" defer>
                    e => {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var mobInput = document.querySelector('#mobile_input');//get the input tag.
                     var moby = mobInput.value;//get mobile no. 
                     console.log(moby);//be sure from the variable mob 
                     mobInput.value='';//reset the input tag.
                     return moby;
                    }
                  </script>
                   <!-- query routing on /search_user?mob -->                 
                 
                   <a href="/search_user?mob=moby" class="border-shadow">Search</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something like this and this seems to work.

```
    <form>
        <input type="tel" name="message" id="mobile_input">
        <button type="submit" onclick="handleSearch(document.getElementById('mobile_input').value)">Search</button>
    </form>
                  <!--getting mobile no. from the input tag -->
                  <script type="text/javascript" defer>

               

                    // const handleChange = (value) => {
                    //     var mobInput = value
                    //     console.log(mobInput)
                    //    
                    // }

                    const handleSearch = (input) => {
                        var searchValue = input;
                        console.log("This is the search value " + searchValue)
                        var url = '/search_user?mob=' + searchValue;
                        console.log(url)
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                    
                  </script>
```

Explanation: I changed the a href element for a button element. Every time the button is clicked (onclick) the function handleSearch is called. This function takes as input the value of the input element with ID "mobile_input". Of course, you can clean up the function a bit more. After merging the url basis ('/search_user?mob=') with the input value (searchValue), the handleSearch function should redirect to the url (calling window.location.href). This last one you can of course change for the correct call to the server. Hope this helps.

Side note: you will see that there is a commented-out handleChange function. You could call this function in the input element to keep track of your changes in the console. this function is called using onChange, just like you use onClick with the search button.
For more info:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Please add examples to support your answer.